# Grafana repeated rows are not grouped

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, grafana-templating, grafana-dashboard

I am new to Grafana and I really need help as I'm stuck with an issue from past 3 days.

I have two 'repeated' rows in Grafana dashboard. Each row with few panels in them. Both the rows are repeated for same filter variable.
I want the one row below another, this works fine when there are only one set of rows or individual row of each type.
But when there are multiple selections of filter variable, the rows are not repeated alternatively.

For visualisation:
Say the rows have title A and B.
With single set they are displayed as:
A
B

When they are repeated:
A
A
B
B

But I want it as:
A
B
A
B

How can I achieve this in grafana dashboard?

I am new to Grafana so I tried merging the rows, but nested rows/panels is not supported as per my knowledge.

Comment: It looks like it already supposed to do what you describe: https://play.grafana.org/d/I0YIojp7z/repeating-a-row-with-a-repeating-vertical-panel?orgId=1&var-vertical=All&var-horizontal=All&var-row=All

Comment: @markalex the link you sent is example of filter for individual rows, but what I am trying to achieve is two rows which are repeated for a single filter. And they need to be together before the next repeated set of these two rows shows up

Comment: This is not achievable. I believe all you can do, in this situation, is to place all panels into a single row, and repeat it.

Comment: @markalex ok, I guess that's the only way to go. Thanks :)